nginx rewrite rules and PHP configuration for multiple Mediawikis
Can anyone help me set up nginx rewrite rules for multiple wikis?
I am running multiple Mediawiki wikis from a common installation, with a separate wiki for each language.  E.g.

example.org/wiki/en/
example.org/wiki/fr/

Problem
I have these two (so far), and I got them to load, but problems remain:

creating a new page on the French (i.e. example.org/wiki/fr/) wiki re-directs to the English (i.e. example.org/wiki/en/) wiki

For example, if I try to create Main_page on the French wiki, it re-directs and
attempts to edit the existing Main_page on the English wiki @ example.org/wiki/en/Main_Page



The URL while editing/creating  goes to example.org/wiki/ instead of the appropriate language subdirectory.



For example, example.org/wiki/index.php?title=Foo&veaction=edit, when it should have a language subdirectory.

How do I rectify this?
directory layout:
/srv/live/php/mediawiki-1.42.1/

    ...
    settings/
        example.org/
            LocalSettings.en.php
            LocalSettings.fr.php
    LocalSettings.php
    ...

Configuration files
/etc/nginx/sites_available/example.org.conf
# example.org
server 
{
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;    # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;      # managed by Certbot

    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name         example.org;
    root            /srv/live/static/example.org/www;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.org/access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.org/error.log;


    location ^~ /wiki/
    {
        alias /srv/live/php/mediawiki-1.42.1/;

        # Redirect /wiki/ to /wiki/en/
        location = /wiki/
        {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/wiki/en/;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ @mediawiki;

        # PHP handling for wiki
        location ~ \.php$ 
        {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param   MW_DB $arg_lang;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @mediawiki
    {
        set $lang 'en';
        if ($uri ~ "^/wiki/(en|fr)/")
        {
            set $lang $1;
        }

        set $wiki_id 'example_org_en';
        if ($lang = 'fr') 
        {
            set $wiki_id 'example_org_fr';
        }

        rewrite "^/wiki/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$" /wiki/index.php?title=$2&lang=$1 last;
        fastcgi_param MW_DB $wiki_id;
    }
}

/srv/live/php/mediawiki-1.42.1/LocalSettings.php
<?php
# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

# Multi-wiki configuration
$wgConf = new SiteConfiguration();

$wikiLangMap = [
    'example_org_en' => 'en',
    'example_org_fr' => 'fr',
];

$wgConf->wikis = array_keys($wikiLangMap);

$wgConf->settings = [
    'wgServer' => [
        'default' => 'https://example.org',
    ],
    'wgSitename' => [
        'default' => example.org Wiki',
    ],
    'wgLanguageCode' => $wikiLangMap,
    'wgDBprefix' => [
        'example_org_en' => 'example_org_en_',
        'example_org_fr' => 'example_org_fr_',
    ],
];

# Determine the current wiki
$wikis = [
    'example.org/wiki/en' => 'example_org_en',
    'example.org/wiki/fr' => 'example_org_fr',
];

if ( defined( 'MW_DB' ) ) 
{
    $wikiID = MW_DB;
}
else
{
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '';
    $parts = explode('/', trim($uri, '/'));
    $lang = $parts[1] ?? 'en';  // Default to 'en' if not specified
    $wikiID = $wikis["example.org/wiki/$lang"] ?? 'exampe_org_en';
}

# Apply the settings
$wgConf->extractAllGlobals( $wikiID );

# Common settings
$wgScriptPath       = '/wiki';
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$wgLanguageCode/$1";

$wgLogos = [
    '1x' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg",
    'icon' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg",
];

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true;
$wgEmergencyContact = '';
$wgPasswordSender = '';
$wgEnotifUserTalk = true;
$wgEnotifWatchlist = true;
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype     = 'mysql';
$wgDBserver   = 'localhost';
$wgDBname     = 'mediawiki_docs_db';
$wgDBuser     = 'wiki_example_org';
$wgDBpassword = 'nope';

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBssl = false;


$wgDBssl = false;
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

$wgSharedTables[] = "actor";

$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = [];

# Include language-specific settings
require_once "/srv/live/php/mediawiki-1.42.1/settings/example.org/LocalSettings.{$wgLanguageCode}.php";




## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

#$wgSitename = 'example';
$wgMetaNamespace = 'example';

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = 'https://example.org';

## The URL paths to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogos = [
    '1x' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg",
    'icon' => "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg",
];

# Shared database table
# This has no effect unless $wgSharedDB is also set.
$wgSharedTables[] = "actor";

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = true;
#$wgUseImageMagick = true;
#$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = '/usr/bin/convert';

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from https://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = true;

# Periodically send a pingback to https://www.mediawiki.org/ with basic data
# about this MediaWiki instance. The Wikimedia Foundation shares this data
# with MediaWiki developers to help guide future development efforts.
$wgPingback = true;

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./includes/languages/data/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = 'en';

# Time zone
$wgLocaltimezone = 'US/Eastern';

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publicly accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

$wgSecretKey = 'haha_wouldnt_you_like_to_know';

# Changing this will log out all existing sessions.
$wgAuthenticationTokenVersion = '1';

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = 'idontthinkso';

$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = 'https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/';
$wgRightsText = 'Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike';
$wgRightsIcon = "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/licenses/cc-by-sa.png";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = '/usr/bin/diff3';

$wgDefaultSkin = 'vector';

# Enabled skins.
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Timeless' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );


wfLoadExtension( 'AbuseFilter' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CategoryTree' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CiteThisPage' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CodeEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ConfirmEdit' );
wfLoadExtension( 'DiscussionTools' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Echo' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Interwiki' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Linter' );
wfLoadExtension( 'LoginNotify' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Math' );
wfLoadExtension( 'MultimediaViewer' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Nuke' );
#wfLoadExtension( 'OATHAuth' );
wfLoadExtension( 'PageImages' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Poem' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ReplaceText' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Scribunto' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SecureLinkFixer' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SpamBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TemplateData' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TextExtracts' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Thanks' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TitleBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );

# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
wgShowExceptionDetails = true;

.../mediawiki-1.42.1/settings/example.org/LocalSettings.en.php
<?php
$wgLanguageCode = 'en';
$wgSitename     = 'example.org Wiki';

.../mediawiki-1.42.1/settings/example.org/LocalSettings.fr.php
<?php
$wgLanguageCode = 'fr';
$wgSitename     = 'example.org Wiki';

Thanks in advance, I am completely stumped.
